# Powershell script streams and events

Tags: c#, powershell, stream

I have a powershell file:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech
$SpeechSynthesizer = New-Object -TypeName System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$SpeechSynthesizer.SetOutputToWaveFile($args[0])
$SpeechSynthesizer.Speak($args[1])
```

And start it via csharp:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processInfo.FileName = @"powershell.exe";
processInfo.Arguments = $"-command {execFile} {tmpFile} '{text}'";
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = processInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

This creates a temp file with a certain spoken text. So far so good. No I want to use the SpeechRecognitionEngine class of System.Speech in that powershell file. What I need is the event SpeechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized and I need the possibility to set the audio input to a stream: SpeechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToAudioStream. So I need the possiblity to send a stream from my csharp file into the powershell script (SpeechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToAudioStream) and the possibilty to call a event in my csharp code triggered by SpeechRecognitionEngine.SpeechRecognized. Is there any possiblity to direct streams into the powershell script and to raise events generated by the powershell script?

Best regards